# Creating Raster Dataset from Point Values using ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, rasterization, raster-conversion

I am using ArcMap.

I'm trying to re-create a map similar to the attached image showing rain gauge locations with a raster dataset that estimates the rain in the surrounding areas based off the information in the rain gauge point data.

I understand the raster dataset was created from the rain gauge point layer, but I've been unsuccessful in creating a similar raster image through any "To Raster" tool use or other creation methods.

I believe this was created using a File Geodatabase Raster Dataset. I have a point layer with updated rain gauge data. I'm experimenting with cell sizing when I attempt to create this raster but have been unsuccessful.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: have you reviewed the metadata of the raster? That might tell you exactly how it was created?

Comment: @Hornbydd I have, unfortunately there's only a Wavelength (nm) property with unknown information under band_1

Comment: Who ever provided you that dataset did a poor job, to provide you with no lineage of how it was constructed is "dropping the ball" and in my mind brings into question the accuracy and value of the dataset! If they haven't even been bothered to tell you how they made it should you be using it? I suspect it was constructed using  an interpolation technique like IDW or possibly an even more advance technique like kriging? I would explore IDW or Spline as a first attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @hornbydd, no metadata is a problem.

The "To Raster" Functions will take existing data and create a raster from it. For example, if you have a feature class of parcel data, you could turn that vector geometry into a raster geometry. Using those tools for a point feature class will not accomplish what you're looking for. You will need to recreate the map from your own geoprocessing.

This is an interpolated surface for sure, when I need to create a continus surface (e.g. raster), spline is always my first bet. It can create values over the minimum and maximum of the input, which can be problematic, though it acts as a good first pass to make a surface, contour it, and look for trends, make a map, etc.

If Spline doesn't meet your requirements, natural neighbor is a powerful un-sung hero esp. with what appears to be some-what normal data distribution (as in, no large swings in the point values). I have been phasing Spline out of my workflows and replace it with Natural Neighbor because I like to "snap" to my data and not create swings in the surface that are outside of the min-max of the data set. It also simple, easy to understand, and sufficient for most normally distributed datasets.

This isn't enough points for Kriging so you will not need to worry about working through the geostatistical wizard.

It is likely there is also a minimum points for Inverse Distance Weighing (IDW) If there are more points in the data you're working with, IDW could be an option.

Here is a nice quick read to get you started on interpolations:
https://www.gisresources.com/types-interpolation-methods_3/
Good luck

Comment: You are correct Mike. I used the IDW tool in Pro and was able to create an almost identical effect from the example above. Thank you so much.